# How to add custom object fields in a pre chat form

Tags: liveagent, einstein, chat, omnichannel

I have to display fields from a custom object in a Pre-chat form. The pre chat form currently allows the fields from standard objects (Case, Lead, Contact).

If we design a VF page to display the custom object fields as a pre chat form, how do we link it up to the embedded service?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can Create a new record from a different Salesforce object
If your business needs a record from a Salesforce object that isn’t available in the standard scenarios, you can define the object in extraPrechatInfo. For example, you can create an account when a chat session starts.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_prechat_code_examples.htm